# Regular expressions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains the following three rows

```
                     name                     
----------------------------------------------
 user - help center test 4 [120,2010-08-19]
 test - help center test 2 [123,2010-01-19]
 help center test [20109,2010-01-01]
(3 rows)
```

Now i need to get a exact match of "help center test" thus it should return the 3rd row. I basically need to do this exact match as if **[20109,2010-01-01]** does not exist in **help center test [20109,2010-01-01]** thus eliminating the brackets and everything within the brackets. NOte the result within the bracket could be anything.

If the brackets weren't there I would use something like
`SELECT name FROM clients WHERE lower(name) like '%call center test%'` and that would give me the result but now I need to do the same with the above results? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-matching.html :

```
SELECT name FROM clients WHERE name ~* 'help center test \\[.*?\\]'
```

Just to clarify that the ~* is a case insensitive match, so there's no need for the lower() function call on the name. This will match all rows that start "help center test [" then have n characters and finally end with "]" (both without double quotes, of course).

Comment: ~ is case sensitive, it did not give me correct results without lower but when I added it in it worked perfectly, thanx alot for this answer, much appreciated. Maybe the case sensitive has somehing to do with my old postgres version 8.1.22 . Thx again

Comment: Sorry - my bad. Fixed accordingly - you should actually use ~* for case insensitivity.